# How can I dump the output of this register , the MSR - IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2 , to see whether unrestricted guest mode is supported/enabled?

Tags: windows, assembly, register

How can I dump the output of this register , the MSR -  IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2 , to see whether unrestricted guest mode is supported/enabled?

Context is curiosity.

I'm aware that Docker in the case of mac osx, and maybe in the case of Windows, requires unrestricted mode / unrestricted guest mode.

And I read

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/virtualization-software-development/topic/277958

"There are a series of MSRs that tell you if a given CPU supports the '1' setting of unrestricted guest and a number of other virtualization features. The specific MSR is IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2 and I believe unrestricted guest is bit 7 in the secondary proc controls VMCS field."

i don't know if powershell or wmic will show it.  I know win7 32bit has debug(which might possible show it?  I know debug can show some registers, I have once used debug to move a value into the AX register), though i'm on win7 64bit and that doesn't have debug.

Perhaps somebody that knows a bit of assembly can show what assembler one needs to install and what lines to run, to display the bits of that register?